# Can we run vba macro on office365 for excel?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Would it be possible to run excel macro on online 365, I have created buttons on home page of excel sheets to run vba.

But every time team has download file on desktop version and run the file which is cumbersome job for them since users are non technical.

Is there any other way we can achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but not in the browser. Excel on the web will not run VBA/Macros.

I would suggest moving away from VBA, perhaps looking at [Office Scripts](https://docs.microsoft.com/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel) or another solution entirely.

Comment: Thank you Trevor

Answer (score 0):

In the SharePoint Online, you cannot run macro in the excel online. You only can run macro in the local office application.

[Work with VBA macros in Excel for the web](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/work-with-vba-macros-in-excel-for-the-web-98784ad0-898c-43aa-a1da-4f0fb5014343?ui=en-us&rs=en-gb&ad=gb)

Comment: Thank you Emily